# Measure battery usage for iOS from Xcode 14

Tags: battery, xcode14

There is a *Energy Profile* in Xcode 12. But can't see this any more in Xcode 14. And even more, it's always showing *Insufficient Metrics Data* for our 5k users app in Xcode organizer. I'm wondering what is the best way to measure the battery usage and find out where to reduce the battery usage.